# How to dynamically create React elements (material-ui) with state expressions in property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I want to dynamically create material-ui context menus within a functional component. Therefore, I use a state as follows

```
 let legendContextMenuStatesObject = {};
  for (let key of keys) {
    legendContextMenuStatesObject[key] = initialState;
  }
  const [legendContextMenuStates, setLegendContextMenuStates] = useState(
    legendContextMenuStatesObject
  );
```

where the initial state is

```
 const initialState = {
  mouseX: null,
  mouseY: null
};
```

Upon right clicking on certain areas I change the corresponding state Object to the mouse event location. The following menus are supposed to pop up then.

```
  function contextMenus(keys) {
    console.log(keys);
    const menues = [];
    for (let key of keys) {
      menues.push(
        <Menu
          keepMounted
          open={legendContextMenuStates[key].mouseY !== null}
          onClose={props.onClose}
          anchorPosition={
            legendContextMenuStates[key].mouseY !== null &&
            legendContextMenuStates[key].mouseX !== null
              ? {
                  top: legendContextMenuStates[key].mouseY,
                  left: legendContextMenuStates[key].mouseX
                }
              : undefined
          }
          anchorReference="anchorPosition"
          TransitionComponent={Fade}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={event => handleClickLegendContextMenu(event, key)}>
            Line style
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      );
    }
    return menues;
  }
```

The state change actually works, but the menus do not appear. 
As far as I understand the problem, the line of code

```
open={legendContextMenuStates[key].mouseY !== null}
```

Is evaluated when creating the Menu elements already rather than inserting the expression making the elements controllable by state changes. 
In fact, I got the context menus working on a different page with a static implementation, meaning I hard code each one instead of creating them in a loop.

I there a way to prevent the open property from being evaluated immediately and actually keeping the expression I want instead?

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I nested Objects within the state. That way not even useEffect recognized any changes in state. 
I solved the problem by using an object of states instead as follows

```
 let legendContextMenuStates = {};
  for (let key of keys) {
    legendContextMenuStates[key] = useState(initialState);
  }
```

Now everything works just fine; also creating the menus dynamically:

```
 function contextMenus() {
    const menus = [];
    for (let key of keys) {
      menus.push(
        <Menu
          keepMounted
          open={legendContextMenuStates[key][0].mouseY !== null}
          onClose={() => {
            legendContextMenuStates[key][1](initialState);
          }}
          anchorPosition={
            legendContextMenuStates[key][0].mouseY !== null &&
            legendContextMenuStates[key][0].mouseX !== null
              ? {
                  top: legendContextMenuStates[key][0].mouseY,
                  left: legendContextMenuStates[key][0].mouseX
                }
              : undefined
          }
          anchorReference="anchorPosition"
          TransitionComponent={Fade}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={event => handleClickLegendContextMenu(event, key)}>
            Color
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={event => handleClickLegendContextMenu(event, key)}>
            Line style
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={event => handleClickLegendContextMenu(event, key)}>
            Line width
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={event => handleClickLegendContextMenu(event, key)}>
            Curve style
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      );
    }
    return menus;
  }
```